# Android - Python communication using zeroMQ

Tags: android, python, zeromq, distributed

With zeroMQ, is it possible to send ('Hello' message) from an Android app I created to a commandline running **`.recv()`** in python?

I made an android app with a button, once pressed it sends "hello" to the `tcp://machine2:5555`.

An extract of the button listener:

```
settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(final View v) {                 
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
            // insert SSH command for ffmpeg here               
            ZMQ.Context ctx = ZMQ.context(1);
            Socket soc = ctx.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
            soc.connect("tcp://192.168.0.16:5555");

            //System.out.print("established");

            String msg = "hi";

            soc.send(msg.getBytes(),0);
        }
    });
```

The python receiver running in the terminal will display the message received.

```
import zmq
import time
import subprocess

port = "5555"

#first create a context for zeroMQ to begin communication
context = zmq.Context()

#pair communication
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)

#bind ip address and port opened for communication
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
print "tcp://192.168.0.16"
while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    if msg is not None:
    print msg
    #run_command(msg)[0]
    #subprocess.call(["mplayer","/home/kevo/capture003.dv"])
    subprocess.call(["time", "mplayer","/home/kevo/Desktop/small.mp4"])
time.sleep(1)
```

But nothing shows on my terminal so far.

Comment: Have you tried a minimalistic-mode working example? Android **.send( ... , zmq.NOBLOCK )**-s each 10 seconds an increasing counter, python **.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )**-s and just print time. Your example shall fix the missing part of the ***MANDATORY*** behaviour for the **REQ/REP** and must also **.send( "got #", zmq.NOBLOCK )** from **REP**-side back to **REQ**, which accordingly has to retrieve from the internal incoming-queue with **.recv( )**, be it algorithmised via blocking or non-blocking mode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I tried the same code with .java, I noticed that libjzmq does not work on my netbeans and eclipse IDE - all recently updated.
the error is below:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe3d03af0d0, pid=2861, tid=140616738543360
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjzmq.so+0x1b0d0]  zmq::socket_base_t::process_stop()+0x40